# TableView habilita botones en una columna al realizar scroll

Tags: java, javafx, scroll, botón

Tengo el siguiente problema tengo un TableView en JavaFX tiene 3 columnas de la cual la ultima columna es un button.
La situación es que el botón debe estar des-habilitado para los primeros 5 registros de la tabla, pero si la tabla cuenta con un scroll lo suficientemente largo para que estos renglones desaparezcan al reaparecer se encuentran rehabilitados.

Si agrego el siguiente codigo no sucede el problema pero también se deshabilitan los eventos de los botones

```
tblCamposMaestro.addEventFilter( Event.ANY, scrollEvent -> {
        tblCamposMaestro.refresh();
    });
```

Intente con este código pero no funciona por alguna razón que escapa a mi comprensión:

`tblCamposMaestro.addEventFilter( ScrollEvent.ANY, scrollEvent -> {
        tblCamposMaestro.refresh();
    });`

La tabla es llenada de las siguiente manera:

```
introducir el código aquí 
 private void crearColumnas(){
    columnaNombre = new TableColumn("Nombre");
    columnaTipo = new TableColumn("Tipo");
    columnaEliminar = new TableColumn("Eliminar");

    columnaNombre.prefWidthProperty().bind(tabla.widthProperty().divide(3));
    columnaTipo.prefWidthProperty().bind(tabla.widthProperty().divide(3));
    columnaEliminar.prefWidthProperty().bind(tabla.widthProperty().divide(3));

    columnaNombre.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn<Object, String>, TableCell<Object,String>>(){
    @Override 
    public TableCell<Object, String> call(TableColumn<Object, String> param){
        TableCell tc = new TableCell<Object, String>(){
            @Override 
            protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty){
                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                if (getIndex() >= 0 && getIndex() <campos.size()) {
                    setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
                    setText(""+ campos.get(getIndex()).getNombre());
                }
            }
        };
        return tc;
     }
    });
    columnaTipo.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn<CampoBD, String>, TableCell<CampoBD,String>>(){
    @Override 
    public TableCell<CampoBD, String> call(TableColumn<CampoBD, String> param){
        TableCell tc = new TableCell<Object, String>(){
            @Override 
            protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty){
                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                if (getIndex() >= 0 && getIndex() <campos.size()) {
                    setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
                    setText(""+ campos.get(getIndex()).getTipo());
                }
            }
        };
        return tc;
     }
    });




    columnaEliminar.setCellValueFactory( new PropertyValueFactory<>( "DUMMY" ) );

    Callback<TableColumn<CampoBD, String>, TableCell<CampoBD, String>> cellFactory = //
            new Callback<TableColumn<CampoBD, String>, TableCell<CampoBD, String>>()
            {
                @Override
                public TableCell call( final TableColumn<CampoBD, String> param )
                {
                    final TableCell<CampoBD, String> cell = new TableCell<CampoBD, String>()
                    {

                        final Button btn = new Button( "Eliminar" );

                        @Override
                        public void updateItem( String item, boolean empty )
                        {
                            super.updateItem( item, empty );
                            if ( empty )
                            {

                            }
                            else
                            {
                                if (getIndex()< 5) {

                                setGraphic( btn );
                                btn.setDisable(true);
                                setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
                                setText( null );
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                btn.setOnAction( ( ActionEvent event ) ->
                                {
                                            CampoBD person = getTableView().getItems().get( getIndex() );
                                            System.out.println( person.getNombre()+ "   " + person.getTipo());
                                } );
                                setGraphic( btn );
                                setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
                                setText( null );
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    };
                    return cell;
                }

    };
    tabla.addEventFilter(ScrollEvent.ANY, scrollEvent -> {
        tabla.refresh();

        // close text box
        tabla.edit(-1, null);
    });

                 columnaEliminar.setCellFactory( cellFactory );
 }

    public void actualizar(List<CampoBD> alumnos) 
    {
    this.campos = FXCollections.observableArrayList(alumnos);
    tabla.setItems(this.campos);
    tabla.addEventFilter(ScrollEvent.ANY, scrollEvent -> {
        tabla.refresh();

    });
    }


 private void agregarColumnas() {
    tabla.getColumns().clear();
    tabla.getColumns().addAll(columnaNombre,columnaTipo,columnaEliminar);
    tabla.addEventFilter(ScrollEvent.ANY, scrollEvent -> {
        tabla.refresh();

    });
}
```

Comment: ¿De alguna forma has llegado a ver que tus botones los tengas deshabilitados en unas filas y en otras no? Comprueba eso porque creo que no se puede. No uso JavaFX pero creo que renderizar la celda lo hace de la misma forma que swing (que es la más eficiente y no puede hacer lo que dices). El resultado sería el mismo que el que quieres, pero no con tu punto de vista.

Comment: En su día me pasó algo similar. No recuerdo exactamente la solución, pero creo que opté por crear el botón dentro del método updateItem (así evito que JavaFX haga caché de esa columna). Si no quieres hacer esto, yo optaría por crear dos botones, uno deshabilitado y otro normal, y asignar uno u otro en updateItem en función del índice. Si utilizas el mismo para ambas situaciones, creo que javaFX cachea algo internamente y no obtienes el resultado que quieres.

Comment: @carlosmoncan lo que hace es que sólo renderiza el mismo botón varias veces, pero no inserta un nuevo botón cada vez (lo cual es más eficiente), por eso dices que te funciono haciendo dos distintos. Yo prefiero usar uno solo y marcar las diferencias en el  `actionPerformed`. Por eso le hice esa preguna al OP, para saber si JavaFX es igual que swing y darle una solución.